# Android -passing intents between activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, textview, android-edittext

I need to pass the login details to another activity called AfterLogin via intents.bt when i run the following code it  says that "Sorry ! The application login has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again." Can someone help me? Iam attaching my code  here.Please help me

Comment: try it http://www.google.co.in/search?ix=sea&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Android+-passing+intents+between+activities#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=Android+-passing+data+between+activities&pbx=1&oq=Android+-passing+data+between+activities&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=6266l7131l0l7911l5l5l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=852d593bb6164c40&biw=1353&bih=1070&ix=sea

Comment: Can u copy paste logcat report so that we can identify error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you specify the 2nd activity you are using to the AndroidManifest.xml file ? By doing so, you'll let the system know that you are using it. see : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Comment: berkantk i have added the second activity to the manifest file using the following code
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="AfterLogin"> </activity>

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your activity in application section in AndroidManifest.xml:

<activity android:name=".YOUR_CLASS_NAME" android:label="LABEL_IF_NEEDED"/>

Comment: hey is it necessary to'.'  before YOUR_CLASS_NAME?

Comment: yep, it is. dot is necessary.

Comment: Ok. Run your application in debug mode and paste full stack error here.

Comment: hey it has some problem with layout.Now it  is working correctly for 1st intent.then it stops execution after startActivity() of 2nd intent.I have set the intent filter for 3 activities as   shown below.Can you help me?
**<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>**

Comment: You need MAIN and LAUNCHER only for the first activity. The remaining activity must be empty. I think so.